# JavaFX Parameter passing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, parameter-passing, fxml

I've been endlessly struggling with this code, I'm trying to send the values of 2 strings to another "window" to perform a function on them but I keep getting all sorts of errors.

I've thoroughly read the [Dependancy Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310) thread and the main problem with it was with the (Pane) cast in the 10th line.

Also, I've read [this one as well](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2395102?tstart=0) and the answer and the code is just plain chaotic.

What I am really trying to do is this:

I have lets say Main document and I'm trying to send one of its values to its CHILD:

My code is like this for the MAINcontroller:

```
@FXML
void initialize() throws MalformedURLException
{
   parameterSender.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Parent root;
            try
            {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filetree/childWindow.fxml"),resources);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle("Child");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
                FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filetree/childWindow.fxml"), resources); //I fixed this, thank you very much, Uchiha Itachi
                childWindowController controller = loader.<childWindowController>getController();
                controller.firstParameter = getFirstField(); //this is the getter of the firstTextAreaField
                controller.secondParameter = getSecondField();//this is the getter of the secondTextAreaField
                stage.show();
                } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//End of Catch
}//End of Initialize
```

And for the CHILDcontroller:

```
@FXML
void testAcquiredParametersFromParent(MouseEvent event)
{
    System.out.println(firstParameter + " " + secondParameter);
}
```

When I run this code I get this exception on runtime:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
at filetree.FXMLDocumentController$5.handle(FXMLDocumentController.java:17)
at filetree.FXMLDocumentController$5.handle(FXMLDocumentController.java:3)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6867)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3311)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3151)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3106)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2248)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT\ Fixed the loader. Again, thanks Uchiha Itachi.

Comment: Just do it the same way as the first example in the [Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310) thread you referenced. Your code is very different to that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is basically because of the below line

```
FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().
                              getResource("filetree/childWindow.fxml"), resources);
```

Here, you are trying to create a FXMLLoader reference, but instead you have used the `load()` of the `FXMLLoader`.

**FXMLLoader's** `load()` will load the Pane which is used as the **root** in the **FXML**. So, instead of using

```
FXMLLoader.load()
```

you must directly use

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().
                              getResource("filetree/childWindow.fxml"), resources);
```